# Does this video bitrate calculation make sense?

Tags: video, bitrate

For the purpose of this question, I downloaded the video at:

- https://imgur.com/gallery/ypkZjqm

It downloaded as "3Uyndrm.mp4", 4,762 kB

In Windows 11, I used File Explorer > Details to view its properties:

[image]

In these data, the `Data rate` is the video bitrate and

- `Total bitrate` = Audio `Bit rate` + Video `Data rate`

This is confirmed by calculating the size of the file from these numbers:

```
File size = 1,765,000 bits/sec * 22 second / 8 / 1024 = 4,740 kB
```

But there's something I don't understand about these these numbers.

We can calculate the number of pixels per second in the video:

```
(854 * 480) pixels/frame * 30 frames/sec = 12,297,600 pixels/sec
```

From that, we can get the number of video bits per pixel:

```
1,635,000 bits per sec / 12,297,600 pixels/sec / 8 = 0.017 byte/pixel
```

Does this make sense? It means that the data for the video are a tiny fraction of a byte per pixel in each frame. I would have thought that each pixel would require at least three bytes for its color values. Reducing that from 3 to 0.017 would be more than 99% compression, which is larger than any compression ratio I've ever heard of.

Is there something wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Video compression is almost magical, right? What's in the video? Lots of movement? Scene changes? What's the codec used? What's the pixel format?

Comment: @DanielB - I provided a link to the video so you could see exactly what video the calculation is for.

Comment: The chroma is sub-sampled in a YUV 4:2:0 pattern, so only one pair of U/V chroma samples per 4 luma (Y) samples.  `mediainfo` calculates it as `0.133 Bits/(Pixel*Frame)`.  (https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo - open source free software).  YUV420 is standard for video outside of high-bitrate formats used while recording and editing, or cinema.  (i.e. any `.mp4` you find on the internet except from video nerds demoing different formats; e.g. ffmpeg with x264 can encode and decode h.264 with High 4:2:2 or High 4:4:4 profile https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Profiles)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the video they can have a main frame that is essentially a compressed image in a lossy format similar to a JPEG. This is an `i-frame` that contains actual image data.

JPEG already achieves somewhere in the order of 10:1 compression with minimal loss of quality, newer video codecs are probably at least as good.

If the next few frames contain a lot of very similar data but a small amount of movement you can simply have a bit of data that says "move these areas of the image by x pixels" and then only compress actual *new* image data that wasn't already on screen. This is a `p-frame`, or a predicted frame based on a previous one.

If you have a series of successive `p-frames` after an `i-frame` you could essentially wipe out an entire series of frames. You would be reducing 8 full frames of data down to 1 single compressed frame along with a small amount of data giving transforms and mathematical calculations.

At 25 frames per second if you have an i-frame every eighth frame you could reduce the amount of data by a very significant quantity. Potentially it could reduce the data to somewhere around 1/8th plus some new parts of the image.

Then there are `b-frames`, bi-directional predicted frames. These can look back at previous `i-frames`, but they can also look forward to the *next* `i-frame`. If you know that there is new data in the next full image then you can use that data to encode even less data in the current `b-frame` and rely on an `i-frame` even further ahead.

These predicted frames can massively reduce the amount of actual encoded data, but at the cost of increased processing power required to encode and decode the video. You need a lot of processing power to look back and forwards across the series of images and figure out all the similarities and differences and apply transforms, blends, blurs, motions and so on.

It also costs the decoder because you need to buffer at least two `i-frames` in order to re-create all the frames in-between.

By offloading a lot of data into equations detailing transforms and motions you can reduce the bitrate far, far below what you would expect, and achieve compression ratios far higher, especially for video without much in the way of motion or changes between frames.

The video you linked shows some artefacts of highly compressed `i-frames` and has very little in the way of motion. It could easily get very high compression ratios.

You can get more information on the basics of the process at [Wikipedia: Video compression picture types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)

Comment: Interesting, Could you say what you mean by "artefacts of highly compressed `i-frames`"?

Comment: @NewSites the image is generally low quality and there are square noisy blocks that follow the player on the far left. Look at the player on the left where the pipe from his mouth crosses the near black of the tree. A section of noise in the `i-frame` has been captured and is being moved around for a few frames before the pattern changes slightly, and for a brief moment where the girl to his right moves over the tree there are a few lighter frames where that block moves. Higher video quality would be better at hiding those blocks. Low bitrates struggle to encode high contrast sections well.

Comment: I expanded it as much as I can on my display and watched it about a dozen times and don't see what you're talking about, so I guess it takes a trained eye to see it. But I'll take your word for it. I take your answer to mean that there is nothing wrong with my calculation and it does make sense. A big surprise to learn about such a high level of compression. Thank you.

Comment: Mokubai: I've posted a follow-up question. Could you please take a look and see if you have an answer? -- https://superuser.com/questions/1835336/how-can-i-know-how-much-video-compression-to-expect

Comment: h.264 I-frames (and JPEG) are lossy not lossless.  (Unless you encoded with x264 `-qp 0` lossless encoding!)  Lossless compression (like PNG or lossless h.264) has a much worse compression ratio than this file compressed with x264 CRF=23 which is the default.  (Looks like preset=faster, for subme=4 and ref=2 among other things, saving CPU time but getting a worse tradeoff between bitrate and quality.  And profile=baseline instead of the default `high`, so no CABAC (only the less efficient CAVLC entropy coder for the final bitstream) and no B frames, so another maybe 10% worse qual / bitrate.)

Comment: Also, B frames can use previous P or even B frames as references (x264 `--b-pyramid` is on by default), not just the previous I frame.   Also, your example I-frame interval is insanely frequent.  This actual video was encoded with `keyint=250 keyint_min=25`, so a minimum interval of 25 frames between I frames.  (Actually x264 *can* use an I frame more often, but it won't be a *key* frame; it won't stop the encoder from referencing earlier frames.)  Most P frames use another very recent P frame as a reference, although the encoder can keep multiple old frames around as references.  (@NewSites)

Comment: (`ref=2` limits the size of the reference list to 2.  The encoder can still look for matches in more frames as part of deciding which frames to keep as references, but the decoder only needs space for 2 reference pictures plus the one being decoded.  Or more for multi-threading if different threads are working on different frames.)

Comment: BTW, we know the video in question was encoded by x264 because x264's encoding settings string (ASCII) is still there in the bitstream header.  You can see it with `strings -n 20 foo.mp4 | less` or with a tool like `mediainfo`.  (https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo).  x264 is the de-facto standard free software encoder, and one of the highest quality encoders.  Some are faster, especially ones that use dedicated hardware like nvidia or intel, and these days some of those are not bad quality, but x264 preset=slower or veryslow is pretty much the gold standard for quality per bitrate AFAIK.

Comment: https://www.vcodex.com/an-overview-of-h264-advanced-video-coding/ has a summary of  of how h.264 finds redundancy (including intra prediction in I frames, predicting from similar blocks in the same frame, and inter prediction from blocks in other frames), and DCT transforms + quantizes the difference between the prediction and the actual pixels.  h.265 is a more recent and standard that isn't much more complicated, and https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=167081 explains it in good technical detail.  But IIRC doesn't cover basics like DCT (discrete cosine transform) used in JPEG.

Comment: @NewSites: If you can't see the artifacting around the player's heads, use a video player that lets you zoom in.  (Like https://mpv.io/ - zoom with ctrl-z and ctrl-shift-z).  It becomes very obvious - some artifacts are more visible when paused, some are more noticeable when playing.  Look at how the background is kind of blurred in the area that's covered and uncovered by their motion, for example.  (h.264 has a deblocking filter as part of the codec itself, so you don't see as much ringing or sharp block edges as in a low-quality JPEG. Filtering happens before frames are used as P/B refs.)

Comment: (Despite a lot of technical details being not quite right in this answer, it does make the key point that video has a lot of redundancy, especially temporal (between frames), and modern video codecs are fairly good at finding it.  e.g. when the camera pans a bit, all pixels shift a bit, so each block will have a similar motion vector vs. the previous frame, so predicting motion vectors from nearby blocks will often make it very cheap to encode, although motion isn't always a whole # of pixles.  Of course a fixed camera, not hand-held, with no noise / grain, will compress significantly better.)

Comment: @PeterCordes rather than calling out specific codecs and their features I was aiming for the "broad strokes" that there is indeed a lot of redundant and reused information between frames. The "lossless" JPEG is obviously wrong and I think was a mobile phone typo where I started writing the answer so I've fixed that. Your other comments are valid and more specific to how the codecs work in particular, I was just pulling numbers out of the air to demonstrate a point rather than be 100% accurate.

Comment: I think all modern video codecs have P (and B-frames if used) reference the last (or a recent) P-frame, rather than increasingly large changes from the last I-frame.  Your answer doesn't say either way for P frame, but implies B frames just reference between two I frames.  Having the decoder keep multiple reference pictures to choose from is also not unique to h.264, nor is a much larger keyframe interval.  Some online video gets encoded with very short keyframe intervals like maybe 1 second or sometimes even half a second for easier seek, but that's still at least 12 frames. And 90 is common.