# How can I know how much video compression to expect?

Tags: video, compression

I'm struggling to learn about video compression. I've learned about H.265 and bit rates. I've downloaded HandBrake and tried it out on a test file. So far, in the two tests I ran, the output files are bigger than the original. I wonder if this means my test file is already squeezed as small as possible.

What I want to accomplish: I've got hundreds of video files on my computer and I'm starting to work with videos more than before. I want to compress what I have as much as is reasonable without detectable quality loss. And I want to do the same with new videos that I'm working with.

Is there a test I can run on a video file that will tell me something like the following?:

- "This file is using *xyz* method of compression with parameters *pqr*,"

and then add either

- "It is compressed about as much as possible without detectable quality loss,"

or

- "It could be compressed another *m*% if you do *abc* to it."

If that's too much to ask for, how close can I come to any kind of similar information, so I'm not left just adjusting HandBrake's `RF` by trial and error?

Comment: One of the problems with video compression that it is hard to predict (e.g. some security webcam files end up being 1% of their original size, while other video files are 95%). You have to go through frame by frame so compressing is as fast as an accurate prediction of how much you can compress without losing quality.

Comment: Video is normally compressed with lossy compression, so you can always compress it more and make the quality worse. Usually you start with some reasonable medium setting, then look at what it did - if the file is still too big, make the compression stronger and try again. If the quality is noticeably bad, make the compression weaker and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *it depends*.  There are entire books on [Video quality metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_quality#Examples_of_video_quality_metrics)

You cannot simply look at a video and *know* what quality settings it has. At best you can guess by looking at the resolution, the bitrate, the encoding features used. A lot of it depends on your source data in that particular moment. A video with a film grain effect will encode very differently than one without.

There are various tools to [measure video quality](https://jnduquesne.medium.com/video-bench-how-measure-your-video-quality-easily-85a0feb8f6e2) and give some indication of what to expect, but it boils down to getting (for example) 30 second samples of your input, making a bunch of encoded outputs and then using the tool to see if what effect various settings had on the perceived quality. There is no "one size fits all" because there is no one way that cameras, post-processing effects, encoders and other things get applied to all the various videos out there.

Some things to bear in mind:

What is your source, how much movement is there in the video?

- High motion means more things are changing quickly and the encoder needs more bits per second to represent those changes.
- This plays very much into the type of content being encoded. Some encoders are geared towards "real world" content, meaning that they can more efficiently represent noisy transitions in colour (as happens in the real world) than they can solid blocks of a single colour. This can present as [banding](https://guide.encode.moe/encoding/video-artifacts.html#banding) in a video, where a nearly solid colour can show obvious colour steps in gradients rather than a smooth transition. Real world images tend to have far more imperfections which can be approximated by noise filters.

What quality settings are you using?

- Higher quality settings will use more bits to encode the video, but whether you can distinguish that quality level using your eyeballs is often subjective and depends on your eyesight and sensitivity and awareness of various artifacts in video. Note: this does not necessarily mean higher quality *values* in an encoder, some encoders use lower value numbers to indicate that they are closer to being lossless and therefore higher "quality"
- You should tailor your quality settings to your requirements. Adjust quality (crf) numbers if used to something relevant for your video resolution (there are crf guides on the internet), limit bandwidth of the part if you need to meet certain limits, use variable bitrate encoding to make best use of the bitrate available over time, use advanced encoding features if available and supported by the system you intend to play it on as they can reduce bandwidth required and release it for use elsewhere.

Using *identical* settings to re-encode a video from an already encoded video does not necessarily mean your file will get smaller.

- Encoders and decoders both introduce various artefacts, noise, approximations and other features and mean that what you see may not be pixel perfect identical to the input from your primary source. As a result you end up decoding those "errors" and then re-encoding a new set of errors and approximations.
  You may think that your video quality is so high that it is perfectly replicating the input but almost all modern video is "lossy" and is built on approximations and psychovisual models that allow them to drop imperceptible detail that a human eye is unlikely to notice.
  Lossless video exists, but the bandwidth requirements would be huge. Think 33 Megabytes per second instead of Blu-ray which is ~30 mega*bits* per second. The data requirements for lossless transmission of modern 4K or 8K video is impractical.
- This also plays into something known as [Generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). Every time you decode and re-encode a video you are adding a "generation" (as in parent-child generation) of artefacts to the video. Every successive generation of noise produces more artefacts, which the next generation decoder and encoder has no idea are not meant to be there and so will faithfully try to reproduce while adding their own approximation noise.

I would avoid re-encoding video wherever possible. You might well save space, but you *will* lose *some* video quality. It might be imperceptible, but it is there.

If you are looking for long term archival then the best format to use is the original one you have. Keep that format around, back it up somewhere else if are re-encoding to save space on a current system but don't discard it if at all possible.

Comment: A comment on the question recommended Tdarr. The doc (https://docs.tdarr.io/docs/welcome/what) says "Each file is run through a set of customisable rules to determine whether it needs to be transcoded or not." That sounds like exactly what I want, but your answer seemed to tell me that can't be done. Do you doubt the software can actually do that?